# Make Posts.Id visible when viewing a post in the application

Tags: feature-request, android-app, navigation

First off, hooray for the app \o/ It is a substantial upgrade from the mobile browser .

I have started using it quite a bit lately and really like the feed and other features. I find myself using it as a searching device and use it frequently for wandering through posts. Often times, I will find an interesting question that I'd like to view in another device and possibly engage in. I generally am long-winded and don't answer with one or two liners so, I am going to prefer a different device other than my phone. There are a few built in ways to navigate to this post from the app to a different device (that I'm aware of):

- Favorite it. This is fine for getting to it, but it kind of abuses the *Favorites* because, in my opinion, favorites are questions that you want to be able to get back to at any point, not a device sharing tool. I really only use favorites for questions that I am going to access on a regular basis and I'd like to keep it that way.
- Share it. You have a few options here, but they all include using some third-party for getting the Post Id via copy/paste, email, etc.

**There's no way to view a post's Id when viewing a post.** What I'd really prefer is some way of seeing the post's Id so I can quickly navigate to it on other devices. I don't really care how noticeable it is, as I know not all users will care to have this, but I still think it'd be nice to have a way of quickly identifying a post so that I can switch to another device, navigate to the site that I was viewing and search the post Id to go directly to the question.

As a suggestion, maybe adding it to the question options header so that it reads:

> Question 12345 options

[image: possible locations]

---

### Edit: Another suggestion

Make a question option `View details` or something similarly worded that show a pop-up of details about the post, which obviously will include my coveted post id as well as maybe some metadata about the question, ie created datetime, amount of edits, view count, last active date, related content, ect. Most of this suggested metadata come from the content in the sidebar of a post.

Comment: @StevenV I don't think that's entirely a dupe. It being a different reason to show the ID will likely bring different discussions and potential suggested features/changes etc.

Answer (score 6):

I fully agree that we need better ways of handling cross-viewing-experience syncing of questions. We've been throwing around the idea of creating a list of "Last 10 viewed posts" or something that is synced across all web browsers / apps / etc so you can be reading something on the Android app then instantly continue reading it from your computer and so on.

However, I don't think there's anywhere we can easily put in the post id here without making it seem out of place and confusing most users. I currently click "Open in browser" on the pop-up you posted and copy the URL out of Chrome to whatever I want to view the post on, which seems like an OK compromise for now. I'll change my stance on this if more people are facing the same issue and think leaving the app to fix it is a bad solution.

Comment: I think you might be underestimating your users, although I'm sure you know more about the demographics than me. It just really seems like a hassle to identify the post currently. Keeping a viewed history is a great idea but it will be way more complicated than my request. Maybe even disabled text in the question options with something like `Post Id: 1234`

Comment: @CarrieKendall Doing a disabled option in the pop-up would lead to lots of confusion -- I'll think about this some more. We might be able to find somewhere to tuck it that won't be too hard for you to find, and out of the view enough to not confuse others.

Comment: You could right-align "Viewing question #" in smaller, grey text at the bottom of the dialog, I guess. It would probably be visually distinct/subtle enough not to cause confusion for most people...but then again I may be giving most people too much credit. Might also go against the platform style guidelines, but I'm a rebel like that. :P

Comment: The idea of a cross-platform share list would be kinda nifty though, if there was sufficient demand for it.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi check my edit for another plausible suggestion

Answer (score 1):

wot no freehand curclz?..

Marking as favourite when on the app is a usable option, and then when on the 2nd device just remove that favourite.
Although this is a *bit* messy, as you've said.

However, your request to see the ID means you have to remember it and type it in another device, which is almost as fiddly as adding and removing favourites.
It doesn't sound like a lot of dev work, as I suppose the ID is already available somewhere in the back end.

That said, I don't really see any other use for the ID being visible.
So if you can think of another way which would be useful for many users, and/or perhaps something which introduces an additional use, then you'd be onto a winner.

### Example idea

Stack creates a historical record of what questions you *viewed* when *on the app*, which can be viewed when on other devices.

Some thought is needed, but it's just an example - eg perhaps only last X (60?) questions viewed, and perhaps only stores questions when viewed on the app.

While it would have questions and & answers you do not want to view on another device, you can at least see your most recently viewed questions and know from the title which one you want to answer.

This also means you don't have to immediately jump on to the 2nd device, as you can keep browsing on the app, and later on view the historical list on 2nd device and identify which questions you wanted to answer from the titles.

Just an example, I'm sure there are other options/possibilities. And this example idea would need more thought into how useful it would be for other users for different purposes.

Comment: Considering most android devices are portable, I think it is much easier to use my eyes to look at the Id then type it into a search box :) With that being said, I don't mind the idea of viewed history or something similar to Chrome's history by device. But, the idea of my request was the keep it simple.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Agreed, however in terms of Stack implementing something, they tend not to do so for a single user/small group of users, it usually has to be useful for many users (I of course speculate, and don't speak for Stack, I could be wrong entirely). That said, if it's just a small task, they may implement for providing additional features on the app. Again, I'm not against it, just trying to throw a new perspective on the discussion :)

Comment: [I guess we'll see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242993/make-posts-id-visible-when-viewing-a-post-in-the-application/242996?noredirect=1#comment794307_242997)